# Why does this use of jQuery's keydown repeat all previous calls?

Tags: jquery, keydown

A div element with text inputs is displayed when openDetails() is triggered.

On 'enter' or 'save', selectedRows are retrieved and used to update grid in batchEdit.

Upon subsequent 'enter' or 'save' calls, however, each prior call (with its prior selectedRows) is made again which updates those rows with the current data.

```
  <div class='item-details-form' id="itemDetailsTemplate">
      <div class='item-details-label'>
          Name
      </div>
      <input class='item-details-editor-container editor' type="text" data-editorid='name'></input>

      <hr/>
      <div class='item-details-form-buttons'>
          <button data-action='save'>Save</button>
          <button data-action='cancel'>Cancel</button>
      </div>
  </div>


// called on menu item 'edit' click: 
function openDetails() {

    var selectedRows = grid.getSelectedRows();
    var modal = $("#itemDetailsTemplate");
    modal.css('visibility','visible');        

    modal.keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {

            // update all rows with current values
            batchEdit(modal, selectedRows);
            modal.css('visibility','hidden');
      }
    });

    modal.find("[data-action=save]").click(function() {
          // update all rows with current values
          batchEdit(modal, selectedRows);
          modal.css('visibility','hidden');
    });
}

function batchEdit(modal, selectedRows) {

     var textname = modal.find("[data-editorid=name]");

        dataView.beginUpdate();
        for (row in selectedRows){

              var dataItem = dataView.getItem(row);
              dataItem[textname.attr("data-editorid")] = textname.val();
              dataView.updateItem(dataItem.id, dataItem);

          }

      dataView.endUpdate();

    }

 }
```

Comment: you're registering handlers each time you call `openDetails()`. either register the keydown and click handlers *once* outside of the `openDetails()` method, or deregister them when you're closing the details div.

Comment: code doesn't show where `openDetails()` gets called. `selectedRows` never changes after it is called. Suggest you create a demo for better response in troubleshooting this

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Doing as you suggested solved the problem (registering the keydown/click code outside of openDetails).